# Electric water heaters

Tags: water-heater

I just put in a trailer and was informed that they had just turned on the power. There isn't a water hookup yet. Will it hurt the heater to be on with out water going to it before I can get back?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  If you run the heater without water, the elements will burn out. Unless the heater has a safety limit, that prevents it from running empty.